# How to create view for selected index in Couchbase?

Tags: indexing, view, couchbase

I have created an index on my field `login`:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_login_date ON mybucket (login);
```

I can use it and select fields I want:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM mybucket u
WHERE DATE_DIFF_STR(NOW_STR(), login, 'day') > 30;
```

My question is - how can I create a `View` which will use this index to find docs I want? I need to use `View` in API, but I have no idea how it should looks like. I want this `View` to do same thing as above `SELECT` query. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_login_date ON mybucket (login) USING VIEW
```